# React Native API call and extracting variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, plaid

I'm new to react native, so bear with me here. I have a react native component calling Plaid Link, which returns a public_token. Once I get that, I call Plaid to exchange the public_token for the access_token, which I need to save as a variable.

Currently, I have this call after Plaid Link returns the public_token. I can't tell exactly where the issue is, but I don't think I'm extracting the access_token from the response properly.

```
    //Call Plaid Public Token Exchange: PublicToken -> AccessToken
    fetch("https://sandbox.plaid.com/item/public_token/exchange", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       "client_id": "[ClientID]",
       "secret": "[SandboxSecretID]",
       "public_token": success.publicToken
      }),
    })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(response => {
      console.log(response.content);
      setVariable({ key: 'AccessToken', value: access_token })
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
     });
```

This is the response the call should return (again, trying to save access_token)

{
"access_token": "access-sandbox-xxxxx",
"item_id": "YYYYYYYY",
"request_id": "ZZZZZZZZZ"
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

First declare a useState before everything

```
const [ApiData, setApiData] = useState(
    { access_token : null, item_id : null, request_id : null }
)
```

and then after in your code

```
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
       console.log(response.content);
       setApiData({
            access_token : response.content.access_token
            item_id : response.content.item_id
            request_id : reponse.content.request_id
       })
  })
```

Now you have the access_token stocked in {ApiData.access_token}

Hope this helps and sorry if it doesn't or if I didn't understand your question.